# How to parse all post's url's from blogspot.com blog?

Tags: python, parsing, feedparser

This post is similar to [How can I retrieve all posts from a Blogger (blogspot.com) blog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428897/how-can-i-retrieve-all-posts-from-a-blogger-blogspot-com-blog)

I do

```
import feedparser
url = feedparser.parse('https://www.blogger.com/feeds/1020819187099399113/posts/default?max-results=1000')
for x in url.entries:
    print (str(x.link))
```

I point out `max-results=1000` but

```
len(url['entries'])
500
```

So how to overcome this limitation? Or is there another way to parse all url's from blogspot.com blog?

Comment: Maybe you have to combine it with the _start-index_ parameter and get the posts with several requests.

Comment: @BlackJack THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The desicion is

```
url = feedparser.parse('https://www.blogger.com/feeds/1020819187099399113/posts/default?redirect=false&start-index=50&max-results=500')
for x in url.entries:
    print (str(x.link))
```

The limitation is 500 but we can apply `redirect=false&start-index=50`.
50 means that we start from 50-th element. So we can pass all the posts